# Can anyone tell me why this .SWF loads fine into IE but not firefox or chrome?

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out why this swf which is loaded via javascript which is a requirement will load just fine in ie but not any other browser

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Host&nbsp;Log-in</title>

<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin: auto;" onLoad="javascript: sf.focus()">
<br />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
  function doFSCommand(command, args) {
  }
//-->
</script>

<script language="VBscript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
  sub sf_FSCommand(ByVal command, ByVal args)
    call doFSCommand(command, args)
  end sub
//-->
</script>

<img src="/img/infinite-logo.png" width="248" height="85" alt="Infinite"><br>

<script language="javascript" src="swf.js" ></script>

<br>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
document.write('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="1280" height="753" ID="sf" VIEWASTEXT>');
document.write('  <param name="movie" value="Host Log In.swf" />');
document.write('  <param name="menu" value="false" />');
document.write('  <param name="quality" value="high" />');
document.write('  <param name="wmode" value="window" />');
document.write('  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />');
document.write('  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />');
document.write('  <embed src="Host Log In.swf" quality="high" name="sf" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1280" height="753"></embed>');
document.write('</object>');
```

Comment: I think you're missing the opening `<html>` unless I accidentally edited it out. I can't see what's wrong with your script sorry but it's often easier to use something like [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to do this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/object "At least one of data and type must be defined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<embed>` tag shouldn't be inside the `<object>`. Try moving it outside the `<object>` tag and see if that helps.

Comment: Awesome, that solved it, Thank you. But now IE is throwing an error :  Expected ';' Code:0  Line:93  Char: 7

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<object classid="... height="753" ID="sf" VIEWASTEXT>'); 
...
document.write('</object>');
```

It's a bad idea creating nodes that way. Use `document.createDocumentFragment()` instead.